# Background color is not visible for cardview when i tried running in Kitkat

Tags: android-layout

The white portion is actually card layout. I have kept backgrountTint for it. It is working fine in lollipop and above but appears like this in below lollipop. Is there any way to make it supportive

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHiqx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `backgroundTint` doesn't work on pre-Lollipop devices. For setting `CardView` background color use [`app:cardBackgroundColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardBackgroundColor).

Comment: Perfect solution.. Thanx alot you saved my time.